# How do I fix RDoc 6.5.0 throwing "Tried to load unspecified class: Regexp"?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rdoc

[image: Screenshot]

The error in the screenshot happens whenever I try to run rdoc. It started after I tried to run "rdoc --write-options --exclude ./externals/" to stop it trying to generate docs for everything the projects, including executables. Now, it doesn't get past that error.

The only thing I've found is that the error is likely from the psych gem.

`rdoc 6.5.0`
`psych 5.1.0`